# How to update constraints programatically and solve keyboard issue for login screen

Tags: ios, swift

i have next problem.

I have this login screen

[image]

When login or password textfield is on focus, we shows keyboard. The keyboard overlay my view.

So i tried to make NotificationCenter with observer and realise methods:

```
@objc func kbDidShow(notification : NSNotification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
        let kbFrameSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

        (self.view as! UIScrollView).contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height + kbFrameSize.height)

        (self.view as! UIScrollView).scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: kbFrameSize.height, right: 0)
    }
```

So, when keyboard appears i'm adding kb size for view. Also, you can see that i added scrollview.

[image]

I think that scrollview works correct

**BUT**

When i'm scrolling my login form still overlays by keyboard. And if i'll scroll to end i'll see that my view will repeat, because its with gradient.

I think, the problem why my login form under kb is that my last button in form "Забыли пароль?" has bottom constraint with constant 92 (another elements i'm start counting constraints from this button). When i deleted it, everything works correct, but i cant work without constraint on bottom. Also, i cant change constraint to use top constraint, because for me is very important to have login form 92pt from bottom.

THE SOLUTION i think, will be to add for existing constraint of my button "забыли пароль?" existing constraint + kb height.

**How i can make it?**

My bytton "Забыли пароль?" in code named as forgotPassword

Second question, how i can add animation for smooth scroll of my login form to center of view, when user set login or password field on focus?
I need to set center of field "loginPassword" to view center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag your bottom constraint of the bottom button as IBOulet

and do this

```
    @objc func kbDidShow(notification : NSNotification) {
          guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
          let kbFrameSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue     

           self.buttonBottomcon.constant = kbFrameSize.height

           UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
          {

              self.view.LayoutIfNeeded()

          }

     }
```

and when keyboard is hidden

```
 @objc func kbWillHide(notification : NSNotification) {

       self.buttonBottomcon.constant = 0

       UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
      {

          self.view.LayoutIfNeeded()

      }

 }
```

Comment: Ok, cool! It works for me, but can you tell me how to make it synchronise with keyboard appear? I tried duration 0.3 but its changing constrainst only kb is appeared.

Comment: play with the duration until it fits smoothly also don't forget to remove observers when view Disappears

Answer (score 1):

```
write this code solve your problem:-
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardHideShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardHideShow), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

   @objc func keyboardHideShow()
   {
       self.constraintHeightHeader.constant = (self.topconstraint.constant == new_value) ? old_value : new_value
   }
```